# Async function blocking component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

In an ReactJs application I have a component which is doing some heavy computations and want to display a loading gif while those computations are done. I tried creating the async function in the component in the following two ways:

```js
compute = async (data)=>{
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
          var tensor =  tf.tensor(tokens, [1,100])
          console.log("start prediction")
          var prediction=this.model.predict(tensor); // this is the heavy computation
          prediction.data().then((result)=>resolve(result))     
      });
    return promise 
}
```

```js
compute = async (data)=>{
    var tensor =  tf.tensor(tokens, [1,100])
    console.log("start prediction")
    var prediction=this.model.predict(tensor); // this is the heavy computation
    return prediction.data()  
}
```

This function is called when the user clicks on a button:

```js
onClickCompute=()=>{
    this.setState({ loading: true },()=>{
        this.compute(data).then((data)=>{
          this.setState({result:data,loading:false})
        })
     });
}
```

My problem is (with both versions for the async function) that while the computations are done the gif which should be displayed is frozen and doesnt show the animation. 
I was assuming that the async pattern is sufficient to perform the computations in the background without blocking the DOM.

If that is not the case how can I solve my problem? Do I need to put the computations in a seperate worker?

Comment: Without using await, async has no effect. The keyword async only allows to use the await as far as I know.

Comment: Please give the full 'onClickCompute' because the problem is not what you think

Comment: You have to return a Promise from your compute method. And you have to set your loading flag true before calling compute method and set false after ending computation.

Comment: I added more code for both functions. Also with returning a promise the code freezes while predict() is being executed.